# How to configure jenkinsfile to analyze python code with sonar

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, sonarqube

I wrote something like this but not working.

```
stage('SonarQube Analysis')
    {
     withSonarQubeEnv('sonar')
     {
         sh "python hello_world.py sonar:sonar"
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: *but not working* is not an error description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SonarPython](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) to achieve that.

Follow the [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) on how to configure SonarPython and perform static code analysis on your Python project.

Comment: This will not help to create a functioning Jenkins Pipeline with SonarQube. SonarPython has no documentation for how to use it with a Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Like described in the [SonarPython documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) you need to run `sonar-scanner`, documentation about using `sonar-scanner` with `Jenkins` is here: [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)

For example:

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
  // requires SonarQube Scanner 2.8+
  def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner 2.8';
  withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
    sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
  }
}
```